# Matching Argument and Result Types in .NET Web Method (SOAP)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I am porting an existing SOAP Web Service to an C# Web Service.  This is brownfield development so I am required to stick to the existing schema/WSDL.  I am writing the Web Service by hand (not generating anything).

My problem seems to revolve around the fact that my Web Method has the **same XSD type for its parameter and return type**.  I used XSD.exe to generate the associated classes for all of the schemas.

Here is my Web Method:

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("soapHeader")]
[SoapDocumentMethod(Action = "ActionURI", Binding = "myBinding", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
[return: XmlElement("UQL", Namespace = "UQLNamespace")]
public UQL UQL([XmlAnyElement("UQL", Namespace = "UQLNamespace")] XmlElement wspRequest)
{ .. }
```

This method expects an incoming message like so:

```
<soap:envelope>
  <soap:header>...</soap:header>
  <soap:body>
    <UQLNamespace:UQL>
      <childOne>...</childOne>
      <childTwo>...</childTwo>
      <childThree>
        <childThreeA>...</childThreeA>
      </childThree>
    </UQLNamespace:UQL>
  </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

It should return a message like so:

```
<soap:envelope>
  <soap:body>
    <UQLNamespace:UQL>
      ...
    </UQLNamespace:UQL>
  </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

The XSD.exe generated class looks like:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="UQLNamespace")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="UQLNamespace", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class UQL { .. }
```

Now the problem is that I get a reflection error when I call the Web Service with an appropriate message format (as shown above).

> Method YourWebService.UQL can not be reflected.  There was an error
>   reflecting 'UQLResult'.  The top XML element 'UQL' from namespace
>   'UQLNamespace' references distinct types System.Xml.XmlElement and
>   UQL.  Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for
>   the element or types.

Now if I remove the `[return: ...]` annotation from the Web Method it will return successfully but it will return XML with the element name `UQLResult` rather than `UQL`. Which is of course not what I need.

Do you have any ideas how I can resolve the conflict in the exception above?

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? If you're not using .NET 2.0 or below, then you should be using WCF instead of ASMX web services, which are now a legacy technology.

Comment: And why are you not using the `UQL` class as the parameter to the web method? I think that's your problem.

Comment: .NET 4.0.  I have to use XmlAnyElement since this is a RequestElement Routing Style and the top level element within `<soap:body>` has multiple children.

Comment: Please show that in your posted XML. From what you're showing, there's no reason not to use `UQL`.

Comment: I've updated the expected XML to reflect multiple child elements under the "routing" element.  Also, if I try to use UQL as the parameter type in my web method, it tells me it does not recognize my request element.

Comment: I don't have as much time as I'd like to try this myself, but I recommend you change the name of the method to something other than `UQL`.

Comment: Thanks John.  I've tried renaming the method and then specifying the MessageName property in the WebMethod annotation but achieve the same result (UQLResult reflection error).

Comment: Well, keep in mind that if it's a bug in ASMX, then it won't be fixed. You should really switch to WCF before spending too much time beating a dead horse. Beat a live one instead.